# is it possible, and how, to use Grpc.Core from a dotnet 4.6 app and to use https without authentification

Tags: .net, grpc

I git and run the sample: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Greeter

which use `Grpc.Net.Client`.

This package is not available for non core apps.

All my searches point me to `Grpc.Core.Channel` to replace `var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");`

I make several try to connect a dotnet 4.6 app to the service provided by the previously referenced git.

```
Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

SslCredentials ssl = new SslCredentials();
Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ssl);

Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, 
                     new List<ChannelOption> {
                        new ChannelOption("InsecureSkipVerify", "True") });
```

the only succes I get is when I edit the service settings from `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"` to `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001"`

Then using

```
Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

is OK.

So is there a way to reach (without authentification) the service with https ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the server from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Greeter/Server exposes the service under https (you'd have to specify options accordingly and use a server-side certificate). Other examples demonstrate how create a (secure) server that supports https.

Once you setup a server that actually exposes https: On the client side, you need to specify the certificate roots that correspond to the certificate used by the server, otherwise the connection would be rejected.

Feel free to refer to examples here:
https://github.com/jtattermusch/grpc-authentication-kubernetes-examples
and here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Certifier/